# Как установить картинку фоном для слайда? Почему у картинки нулевая высота?

Tags: javascript, html, вёрстка, scss, background

Пытаюсь сверстать слайдер [по уроку](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GNvcGNx5zgQ&list=PLM6XATa8CAG6MOSVCJPNS9ARQ518hPBjF&ab_channel=%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8-IT%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81) (1 22 00). Использую такую разметку:

```
div class="main-slider">
            <div class="main-slider__body">
                <div class="main-slider__item item-main-slider">
                    <div class="item-main-slider__contant">
                        <div class="main-slider__container _container">
                        <div class="title">
                            <div class="title__item">Только эксклюзивные</div>
                            <div class="title__main title__main-white title__main-regular ">Лоты под аукцион и свобоДную продажу</div>
                            <div class="title__text">Мы собираем эксклюзивную публику и экслюзивные лоты, даем удобный и автоматизированный сервис по покупке и продаже, а также выставлению лотов на аукцион, предоставляем личные кабинеты, а также оказываем сопутствубщие услуги с продажей редких и дорогих вещей</div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-main-slider__bg _ibg">
                        <img src="img/main-slider/01.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="main-slider__control"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

scss:

```
// main slider

.item-main-slider {
    position: relative;

    padding: 30px 0 100px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.item-main-slider__content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
.item-main-slider__container {}
.title {}
.title__item {
    font-family: "ceremonious";
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #bb9c66;
}
.title__main {
    font-size: 35px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: "pfdin";
    font-weight: 500;
}
.title__main-white{
    color: #fff;
}
.title__main-regular{
    font-weight: 400;
}
.main-slider-item__text {
color: #fff;
font-size: 15px;
line-height: calc(25/15);
max-width: 700px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.item-main-slider__bg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;

}
._ibg{
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: relative;

img{
width: 0;
height: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
}
}
```

и js для того, чтобы установить картинку задним фоном, через background-image для IE11:

```
function ibg(){

let ibg=document.querySelectorAll("._ibg");
for (var i = 0; i < ibg.length; i++) {
if(ibg[i].querySelector('img')){
if(document.querySelector('body').classList.contains("no-webp")){
ibg[i].style.backgroundImage = 'url('+ibg[i].querySelector('img').getAttribute('src')+')';
}
else{
let path = ""+ibg[i].querySelector('img').getAttribute('src').split('.')[0]+".webp";
ibg[i].style.backgroundImage = 'url('+path+')';
}
}
}
}

ibg();
```

Не могу понять почему высота фоновой картинки устанавливается в 0px и соответственно ее не видно. Помогите исправить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<div class="item-main-slider__bg _ibg">
  <img src="img/main-slider/01.png" alt="">
</div>
```

```css
img{
//вот и ошибка
width: 0;
height: 0;
//
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
}
}
```

У вас товарищ картинка высотой 0 и шириной 0. Вы классы присваиваете к обёртке изображения и соответственно на само изображение действует только css для тега `img`. Добавьте к изображению класс, где задаёте высоту и ширину или уберите нули из `img`.
Надеюсь помог.

Вот попробовал исправить то, что у вас там написано. Во-первых у вас скобки поехали, а во-вторых `что-то_там_content` в html написано как `contant`. Ну и посмотрите, что я там закоментировал. И еще добавил `z-index`. А с вашим js Я не стал разбираться.
Код:

```css
// main slider

.item-main-slider {
    position: relative;

    padding: 30px 0 100px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.item-main-slider__content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
.item-main-slider__container {}
.title {}
.title__item {
    font-family: "ceremonious";
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #bb9c66;
}
.title__main {
    font-size: 35px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: "pfdin";
    font-weight: 500;
}
.title__main-white{
    color: #fff;
}
.title__main-regular{
    font-weight: 400;
}
.main-slider-item__text {
color: #fff;
font-size: 15px;
line-height: calc(25/15);
max-width: 700px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.item-main-slider__bg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
._ibg{
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
//position: relative;
}

img{
width: 100%;
//height: 100%;
//position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
//opacity: 0;
//visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-slider">
  <div class="main-slider__body">
    <div class="main-slider__item item-main-slider">
      <div class="item-main-slider__content">
        <div class="main-slider__container _container">
          <div class="title">
            <div class="title__item">Только эксклюзивные</div>
            <div class="title__main title__main-white title__main-regular ">Лоты под аукцион и свобоДную продажу</div>
            <div class="title__text">Мы собираем эксклюзивную публику и экслюзивные лоты, даем удобный и автоматизированный сервис по покупке и продаже, а также выставлению лотов на аукцион, предоставляем личные кабинеты, а также оказываем сопутствубщие услуги с продажей редких
              и дорогих вещей</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item-main-slider__bg _ibg">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/01/26/10/33/chess-4794265_960_720.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-slider__control"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Нули из ing убрал, картинка не появилась. К тому же, когда стояли свойства width : 0; height : 0 ; нулевой была только высота картинки

Comment: А вы `visibility: hidden;` пробовали убирать? Оно по идее делает саму картинку невидимой. Т.е. visibility - видимость, а hidden - скрыта.

Comment: Также и `opacity: 0;`. Opacity - непрозрачность. Может варьироваться от 0 - прозраный, до 1 - непрозрачный.